# What is the js equivalent of jquery 'id$=' ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I do the following in javascript? :

`var ddlorigin = $('select[id$=ddl_originStation] :selected').val();`

Comment: try this: document.getElementById()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an exact equivalent, but you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

```
var el = document.querySelector('select[id$=ddl_originStation]');
if(el){
    var ddlorigin = el.value;
}
```

Comment: if so this is also not an equivalent, how can this target the selected?

Comment: @KingKing see the second part of AppleBud's answer... `el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: Add `:checked` to the selector to get the selected option. Yep, I know it doesn't seem right, but it works.

Comment: what if query selector returns more than 1 element?

Comment: @mercy `querySelector` returns only the first element

Comment: @mercy `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an array... in that case you need to access the element by index

Answer (score -1):

Var el = Document.querySelector(css query);
the same as yours

Comment: You should try your suggestion. `:selected` is **not** a standard _pseudo-class selector_, but a proprietary specialization of `:checked` only supported by e.g. `jQuery`

Comment: I didnt tell any thing like selected or checked. That guy told him that its not in js and I avoid repeating repeatitive thing. Why u downvoted?

Comment: I didn't do the down-vote. But an answer has to be self containing, as the other comments and answers could be deleted. And as the OP asks for an **equivalent** you have to mention in your answer that while `querySelector` can be used `:selected`  is not supported by the standard. Your answer does not show how to do the same thing in _vanilla_ JS.